# AdonisJS Validator throw error even when data is passed correctly

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

My validation class look like this:

```js
export default class CreateUserValidator {
  constructor(protected ctx: HttpContextContract) {}

  public schema = schema.create({
    username: schema.string({}, [
      rules.alpha(),
      rules.unique({ table: 'users', column: 'username' }),
    ]),
    email: schema.string({}, [rules.email(), rules.unique({ table: 'users', column: 'email' })]),
    password: schema.string({}),
    rol: schema.enum([Rol.MANAGER, Rol.SUPERUSER, Rol.WORKER]),
  })

 
  public messages = {}
}
```

and this is my UserController

```js
export default class UsersController {
 
    public async store(ctx: HttpContextContract) {
    console.log(ctx.request.body())
    await ctx.request.validate(CreateUserValidator)
    const user = new User()
    await user
      .fill({
        email: ctx.request.input('email'),
        username: ctx.request.input('username'),
        password: ctx.request.input('password'),
        rol: ctx.request.input('rol'),
      })
      .save()
    console.log(user.$isPersisted)
    return {
      done: true,
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that even if I pass all the data as required it keeps responding with this

```json
  {
    "errors": [
        {
            "rule": "required",
            "field": "username",
            "message": "required validation failed"
        },
        {
            "rule": "required",
            "field": "email",
            "message": "required validation failed"
        },
        {
            "rule": "required",
            "field": "password",
            "message": "required validation failed"
        },
        {
            "rule": "required",
            "field": "rol",
            "message": "required validation failed"
        }
    ]
}
```

I checked and the data is arriving with no problems on the request body, I don't know If I am doing something wrong

Comment: Can you provide your payload for the request?

Answer (score 0):

On `routes.ts` try using post as a method.

Comment: Instead of adding "this should work..." as answers provide detailed answers that will actually provide an answer to the question.